# Could The Doctor's daughter Jenny and Jenny Flint be the same person?

Tags: doctor-who, regeneration

I am not asking if they are because the answer probably is "We don't know". I am curious if there is any evidence against it, or if it is a real option.

[image: Doctor's Daughter] [image: Jenny Flint]

As [the Doctor's daughter](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Jenny_(The_Doctor%27s_Daughter)), the blond Jenny can possibly regenerate, so I think that it is possible that the brown haired [Jenny Flint](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Jenny_Flint) is the Doctor's daughter after some regeneration (one or more) and she has her reasons for not telling him.

Can this theory be true?

Comment: It has been established that Jenny Flint is human, not Timelord, or...Timelord clone.

Comment: @tilley31 Do you have a more specific information about where this was established please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Can* it be true? Sure, any theory *can* be true, that's the beauty of a theory. *Is* it true? Probably not.

We've no reason to believe that Jenny can actually regenerate/change her face and we've also no reason to believe that Ms. Flint is anything other than human. There just isn't any canon material that says otherwise.

Time Lords are known to be able to sense each other, so if Ms. Flint were in fact Jenny, The Doctor would have sensed that a long time ago, what with Jenny having two hearts and all.

Comment: Actually theory can be true if there is no reason for it that proves that this theory is false. I am asking for such proof.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty solid no.

Aside from there being no indication whatsoever to the positive and no sign that the period blond Jenny was left in had time travel available Victorian Jenny was rendered clinically dead for a while in "The Name of the Doctor" before being resuscitated by Strax's knockoff medical tricorder, unless she somehow found and used a chameleon arch he would have noticed that he was restarting more than one heart.